# Cos'è una "zucca da bere"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Sullo stradone e nelle cascine ci stavo meglio, ma neanche qui non mi credevano. Potevo spiegare a qualcuno che quel che cercavo era soltanto di vedere qualcosa che avevo già visto? Vedere dei carri, vedere dei fienili, vedere una bigoncia, una griglia, un fiore di cicoria, un fazzoletto a quadrettoni blu, una **zucca da bere**, un manico di zappa?

Ho cercato alla voce "zucca" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato l'espressione "zucca da bere". Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Immagino che in campagna o comunque presso la povera gente fosse diffusa l'abitudine di utilizzare una zucca scavata come contenitore per l'acqua; da quel che ho visto esiste anche un tipo di varietà di zucca che viene coltivata apposta per questo uso: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagenaria_siceraria

Answer (score 1):

Il significato è più o meno quello indicato da @RiccardoDeContardi nel suo commento. Nell'[articolo](http://www.ircres.cnr.it/images/wp/WP_06_BIORCI_FALAVIGNA.pdf) di Grazia Biorci e Greta Falavigna intitolato "Fame e abbondanza. Il glossario. 
Scelte lessicologiche, criteri di lemmatizzazione e analisi testuale" si parla dell'elaborazione e l'analisi di un glossario che si è costruito basandosi su un corpus di testi, tra i quali c'è appunto il romanzo *La luna e i falò* di Pavese. In questo articolo si spiega che il significato di "zucca da bere" è il seguente:

> La zucca veniva svuotata e lasciata seccare, quindi veniva utilizzata come contenitore per le bevande, più 
>   frequentemente vino.